# How to add an image to be returned by a map in REACT (JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, use-ref

I'm building a chatbox, on a card I have a `messageList` that I made with `useState`:
[image]

[image]

I'm trying to add images to the initMessageList to be displayed on the card with `preview` using `useRef` but it does not show the image (I'm changing the 'messageList' func):

> 

function ConvBoard({ name }) {

```
const [initMessageList, setMessageList] = useState([])

const messageList = initMessageList.map((now, key) => {
    if (now.Image) {
        return <img src={preview} />
    }
    return <Message text={now.text} key={key} />
});

let newText = useRef(null);

const addMessage = () => {
    if (newText.current.value != "") {
        setMessageList([...initMessageList, {
            text: newText.current.value,
            key: initMessageList.length
        }])
        newText.current.value = ""
    }
}

const onKeyFunc = function onKeyEnter(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && newText.current.value != "") {
        { addMessage() };
    }
}

const [image, setImage] = useState();
const [preview, setPreview] = useState();

const pressRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            setPreview(reader.result)
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(image)
        setMessageList([...initMessageList, {
            text: preview,
            key: initMessageList.length
        }])
    } else {
        setPreview(null)
    }
}, [image]);

return (
    <Tab.Pane eventKey={name}>
        <Card className='card'>
            <extraWarper className="extra">
                {messageList}
            </extraWarper>
        </Card>
        <InputGroup>
            <FormControl className='inputLine' ref={newText}
                placeholder="your text" onKeyPress={onKeyFunc}
            />
            <Button variant="outline-secondary">record</Button>
            <DropdownButton title="upload" variant="outline-secondary">
                <button onClick={(event) =>
                    pressRef.current.click()
                }>
                    Send image
                </button>
                <input ref={pressRef} id="filePicker" style={{ display: "none" }} type={"file"}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        const file = event.target.files[0]
                        if (file) {
                            setImage(file)
                        } else {
                            setImage(null)
                        }
                    }
                    } />
            </DropdownButton>
            <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={addMessage}>send</Button>
        </InputGroup>

    </Tab.Pane>
);
```

export default ConvBoard
}

now the site looks like this:
[image]

but when i try to add an Image its blank.
Any ideas?
(Sorry for the mess, and thank you!)

Comment: edit your question because it's no readable..

Answer (score 0):

There is no `now.Image` in this code.

```
    if (now.Image) {
        return <img src={preview} />
    }
    return <Message text={now.text} key={key} />
});
```

there may be `now.Text` which represents `now.Image` and `preview` in your code

because you set it in this part of code

```
 setMessageList([...initMessageList, {
            text: preview,
            key: initMessageList.length
        }])
```